# Search word in attributedString from backword and get range Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nstextattachment

How do I search the space "" (space) in an attributedString from the end of the string backwards and then get the range of that space?

problem : As you can see jumps is in two line which is not correct.

The logic i want to implement is like that, whenever i will get new line i will replace space with \n so that word will start from new line.

whenever i am hitting space button from keyboard , i am storing range of that space and when i am getting newline i am replacing \n with space

[image]

Comment: any example of what you need to achieve?

Comment: There is no such method for this functionality, you have to write your own logic to do so

Comment: Use the `string` (`NSString`) property of the `NSAttributedString`, and use the `NSString` method: `rangeOfString:options:`?

Comment: as you can see jumps word is in two line, so i want go get last space range and replace with "\n" @SuryakantSharma

Comment: I think searching backwards will not really help.  How does your code know that "jumps" is split?  What if user inserts a word before "fox?"  Word breaking is better handled at a lower (framework) level because it depends on screen size, font size, string length, etc.

Comment: I am checking newline, whenever it goes to the new line i will find last space. @Jerry

Comment: If you do that for every newline (ie, search backwards for space), then the result will be a single word on every line.  Please tell me I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Jerry i edited my question, hope you will understand my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution, but my guess is that Apple's frameworks should have something to help you (ie, read more documentation).  If you really want line by line control, you are asking for lower level control than UITextView.  Hope you find it.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code:

```
int spaceIndex = -1

for i = 0 to string.length {
    if string.characters[string.length - i] == " " {
        spaceIndex = string.length - i
        break
    }
}
if spaceIndex != -1 {
// The space index found
}
```